# Find CPU usage using 'top' in Linux and parsing result

Tags: c++, linux

I am writing a C++ program to find the cpu usage of a linux system using 'top' command. I use `system("top -d 1");` to execute top command. Now I wish to get the fourth line of 'top' command. In java I can define a process to execute 'top' command and then use BufferedReader to read the result. What is an alternative for this in C++? EDIT: I need to find the cpu usage of the system at an interval of 1 second. So is there any way other way than writing to a file so that I can get the result of top function every second when it refreshes?

Comment: I think you have to redirect the output to a file or pipe and then read it like you would read a normal file with C++.

Comment: I think there must be duplicates of this. You can use [popen()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).

Comment: Since I need the refreshed result of 'top' every second, writing to a file may not be a good option (my thought).